# Different javascript calculation based on value of input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, calculation

I am trying to create a javascript that has multiple calculations of fees depending on the initial amount entered into an input field. This is basically what needs to happen.

Up to 500,000: the fee would equals 1.00% p.a. More than 500,000  the fee equals 0.85% p.a. More than 1,000,000: fee equals 0.70% p.a.

I have got the first part working being 1% per month i.e amount divided by 100 divided 12 for monthly amount.

How would I apply a different calculation if input is more than 500,000 and a further different calculation for more than 1,000,000.

```
$(function() {
$('#rangeslid').change(function() {
var invest = parseFloat($('#rangeslid').val()) || 0;
let fee = 1;
if (diff > 1000000) {fee = 0.7;} 
else if (diff > 500000) {fee = 0.85;}
var diff = invest / fee / 12;
diff = diff.toFixed(2); 
$('#ongoingadvice').val(diff);
});
});
```

Comment: `var fee; if (x < 500000) {fee = 111; } else if (x<1000000) { fe = 222} else { fee=333}`

Comment: Can you indent your code properly?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to do what i needed the else if statement was not working becuase of the following

```
        <script>  
    $(function() {
$('#rangeslid').change(function() {
var invest = parseFloat($('#rangeslid').val()) || 0;
    
    var feee; 
    if (invest > 500000 && invest <= 1000000) {fee = 0.0085; }
    else if (invest > 1000000) {fee = 0.007;}
    else { fee = 0.01}
    
    
var diff = invest * fee / 12;
diff = diff.toFixed(2); 
$('#ongoingadvice').val(diff);
});
});
            </script>
```